# Does this work to reduce compile time for free template functions?

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I have a Visual Studio 2008 c++03 project where I've come across something like this:

```
//foo.hpp
namespace Foo {
    template< typename T >
    inline void foo( T t )
    {
        // do stuff...
    };
}; // namespace foo

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
namepsace Foo {
    template void foo< int >();
}; // namespace Foo

//main.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    Foo::foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

This does create a foo.obj file that I presume contains `Foo::foo< int >()`, but it does not seem to affect the size of main.obj.

Does this technique work to reduce compile time of template code? Or is it actually increasing compile time because `Foo::foo< int >()` must now be compiled twice?

Thanks

Comment: Seems pointless as the function is `inline`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Functionally, there is no difference. `foo.cpp` only contains a declaration (no definition). The compile time is increased if you include `foo.cpp` in the compilation.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't care about the inlining of the function (which the compiler may override anyway), you can do the following. It won't be perfect but you'll have a real chance to improve the compilation time.

```
//foo.hpp
namespace Foo {
    template< typename T >
    void foo( T t );
}; // namespace foo

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
namespace Foo {
    template< typename T >
    inline void foo( T t )
    {
        // do stuff...
    };
}; // namespace foo

namespace Foo {
    template void foo< int >();
}; // namespace Foo

//main.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    Foo::foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is **no**.
To increase compilation speed you should do:

```
//foo.hpp
namespace Foo {
    template <typename T> void foo( T t );

    template <> void foo<int>(int t);
}; // namespace foo

// foo.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
namepsace Foo {
    template <> void foo<int>(int t)
    {
        // do stuff...
    };
}; // namespace Foo

//main.cpp
#include "foo.hpp"
int main(void)
{
    int a = 5;
    Foo::foo(a);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't get why you feel the need to add the "extern template" declaration.

Comment: I meant to say you didn't need the declaration at all !

Comment: @Benoît Yes. Compiler/linker don't require this declaration. But I consider this declaration for developer.